# Authenticating via Kerberos in Capybara/Poltergeist

Tags: ruby, capybara, kerberos, poltergeist

How can I provide authentication details for a Kerberos-protected web service that I'm testing using Capybara and the Poltergeist driver?

Presumably I need to set an `Www-Authenticate: Negotiate` header, but I haven't the foggiest on how to do this. Most articles I can find are relating to configuring Kerberos for Rack apps, but we're acting as the client for an existing remote web application.

Comment: Do you need that for a client or a server?

Comment: A client. We're using Capybara to hit a remote service that doesn't have a REST API and glean data from it.

Comment: Since this client is written in Ruby, you are going to need a Ruby GSS-API binding. I have found these two: [1](https://github.com/zenchild/gssapi), [2](https://rubygems.org/gems/gssapi). As soon as you have managed to compile the best fitting against MIT Kerberos, I'll tell you what to do.